# Who hugely misunderstood the sentence "Do you feel like breakfast ?"

Tags: story-identification

A scene from an SF book just jumped to my mind. I read it many decades ago. I believe it is a rather famous book, so this question might be a dupe. Still, I have no idea what book it was. But I am asking for the name of the character, not the book...

There was a character that suddenly ended up in completely different surroundings.

Asked the question "Do you feel like breakfast ?" the character says (or maybe just thinks) something like :

"I did not realise food was in so small supply here one needs to eat one of the company."

as if the question was about feeling like becoming the breakfast of people around. So who misunderstood so hugely this innocent question ?

Please note that I meant this as a character identification, so I will only accept an answer that identifies both the story **and** the character.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is properly a character-identification question if you don't know the work it belongs to.

Comment: @DavidW Should I make it a "story-identification" but accept only an answer that specifies the character ?

Comment: @DavidW Well, it is all moot now. Both story and character have been found by Clara Diaz Sanchez...

Comment: Which is why I didn't reply to your first comment; the answer was here already when I saw it. :)  All is good now.

Comment: @DavidW Just out of curiosity, why didn't you VTC this one as off topic? After all, there are no "fantastical elements" in the question.

Comment: @user14111 Oh please.  FWIW, I hold you in enough respect not to reply as your snark would normally warrant, but it is possible for intelligent adults to reach different positions without either being irrational.

Comment: Not to mention that an experienced user is asserting it's SF, the dialog in question is not something that a person raised in our current culture would say, and it's obviously from a very famous work.

Comment: "Ravenous Bugblatter Beasts often make a very good meal _for_ visiting tourists: instead of "Ravenous Bugblatter Beasts often make a very good meal _of_ visiting tourists"

Comment: @TripeHound LOL !

Comment: "Don't call me Shirley"... (smile)

Comment: @Xavier "Clarice", I would have understood. Why "Shirley" ?

Comment: @Alfred Ever watched the movie Airplane (1980)?

Comment: @Xavier No. But since you posted I found the reference and the joke. Still, I don't see the connection with anthropophagy..

Comment: “It's unpleasantly like being drunk."
"What's so unpleasant about being drunk?"
"You ask a glass of water.”

Comment: @user108131 Is it a quote from *Stranger in a strange land* ? I don't quite see the connection.

Comment: No, it is from "The hitch-hikers guide to the galaxy" and while not the answer, I felt it was in the same vein.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This sounds like a scene from *[Stranger in a Strange Land](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1095)*, by Robert A. Heinlein. The thought goes through the mind of the central character, Valentine Michael Smith, when he is being checked in the medical facility after his return to Earth.

> "Good!” the creature echoed. “Doctor Nelson will be along in a minute.
> Feel like breakfast?”
>
> All symbols were in Smith’s vocabulary but he had trouble believing
> that he had heard rightly. He knew that he was food, but he did not
> “feel like” food. Nor had he any warning that he might be selected for
> such honor.”

Comment: Valentine Michael Smith in Stranger in a Strange Land ! Indeed !

Comment: I think it was 50 years ago when I read the book.  Sadly about the only thing I remember from it is "grok".