# Book about a man born in space who returns to Earth with the ability to transcend his body

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book when I was a teen about a set of astronauts who while in space had a child.

The child returns to Earth, older now, maybe 20s/30s without the parents. The adult was human, but had qualities about him that seemed unhuman. A group of scientists were studying him. Among them is a women he bonds with. The man has the ability to transcend or astral travel from his own body, like an outer body experience. I think he had other abilities with electricity as well that I’m not sure about.

He goes to the bottom of a pool and transcends from his body there. He is able to teach a women on Earth to do this outer body experience as well. I think the man from space ends up dying. But before that he does form a loving bond with the women he taught.

Comment: Stranger in a Strange land?

Comment: It does sound so much like that, but I wasn’t sure if it was, I’ll have to reread or read that one because in the info I can’t seem to find if the main character, valentine Michael smith, had the ability to transcend. But maybe it is that one. Ty for the reply I will read and see if it is the same

Comment: For the record, **every** book you read was when you were younger.

Comment: I said when I was a teen though? But sure I agree. Edit oh you mean the title.

Comment: @MRC we do not know when you were a teen, so it is always better to say how many years ago you read a book instead of how old you were.

Comment: "Outer body"? I assume you mean [out-of-body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-body_experience)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "bottom of the pool" thing makes me think it is Heinlein's *Stranger in a Strange Land*.

> "Oh. My dear, it has not yet been declared a crime to be present at a miracle. Nor to work one. But this matter has more aspects than a cat has hair. Keep quiet and let me think."
> Jill kept quiet. Jubal held still about ten minutes. At last he opened his eyes and said, "I don’t see your problem, child. He’s probably lying on the bottom of the pool again-"
> "He is."
> "-so dive in and get him. Dry him off and bring him up to my study."

Mike has also powers over matter. He can *disappear* people:

> When he saw his water brother struck by this other, he twisted and ducked, got free - and *reached* in an odd fashion for Johnson.
>
> Johnson was not there any longer.
>
> He was not anywhere. The room did not contain him.

There's a paragraph where he explains how it would be possible to disintegrate Earth by fissioning a hundred-mile chunk of matter near the planet's core, as the Martian Old Ones did in the faraway past to blow the Fifth Planet up:

> "Jubal, the destruction of the Fifth Planet by the Old Ones is as historically certain as that eruption of Vesuvius - and it is recorded in much greater detail. No myth. Fact. [...] It merely takes [...] the same sort of control that you have seen me use time and again. Simply necessary first to *grok* what you want to manipulate. I can do it unassisted, right now. Say a piece near the core of the planet about a hundred miles in diameter...

... and can remote-view when in a trance. I did not find the exact reference, but somewhere else another character says to Jubal,

> You see, even then, when Mike was asleep - in trance - he could see around him quite a distance and sometimes he would look in on you

There are no references to "power over electricity", but there *is* a strange reference to electricity that got [someone else baffled](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193147/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-c-or-d-c). I also remembered it vaguely. At the time, I did not understand it was jargon.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, another suggested it was this too. I just figured it was not such a famous book. It’s time to read stranger in a strange land and see if it lands the same as when I was a teen. Ty for the reply

Comment: @MRC you could watch the cartoon summary https://youtu.be/3jAkplrZci0?si=oZmiY7cqI6MPH7HD

Comment: In which case, a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/280907/who-hugely-misunderstood-the-sentence-do-you-feel-like-breakfast/280908#280908